# The ratio of two strictly increasing functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra

Given:
\begin{equation}
 f_1(a)=\sum_{i=1}^{k^*-1} \left(\begin{array}{c}
K   \\\
i   \\
  \end{array} \right) \left(-1-\frac{1}{ar}\right)^i
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 f_2(a)=\sum_{i=1}^{k^*-1} \left(\begin{array}{c}
K\\\
i   
  \end{array} \right) \left(-1+\frac{1}{a}\right)^i
\end{equation}
prove or disprove that
\begin{equation}
 f_3(a)=\frac{f_1(a)}{f_2(a)} 
\end{equation}
is an increasing funtion of $a$, 
where $-1< r < 0$ and $0.5 < a < 1$

Comment: Why should we? Where does this question come from? And what is $k^*?$

Comment: This question is a part of a more general proof in detection theory where I am working on. $k^{*} > 2$ and $K > k^{*}$ both $k^{*}$ and $K$ are integers.

Comment: obviously for $k^{*} \geq 2$ too. I will be happy if I will get any answer.d Thanks alot for the visitors of my question..

Comment: For the record, I don't think your tags are very appropriate.